# LaunchApplication in a non-Cocoa app?

Tags: c++, macos

Can the launchApplcation call be usedv in a non-Cocoa app?
I need the equivalent of Windows spawnl(), which executes a application from within another. Is there an OSX equivalent to spawn() or exec()?

I could use the system() call, but I need to add command line arguments to it.

Thanks!

Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have the ability to fork and exec other processes.

For example:

```
int myPipe[2];
int err, child_pid;

err = pipe(&myPipe); //creates the pipe - data written to myPipe[1] can be read from myPipe[0]

child_pid = fork();

if(child_pid == 0)
{
    err = dup2(myPipe[1], 1); //set myprogram's standard output to the input of the pipe

    execl("/path/to/myprogram", "arg1", "arg2");
}

int pipefd = myPipe[0];
char buffer[255];
err read(pipefd, buffer, 255); // etc etc

// Ideally you would check that err and child_pid != -1
```

Comment: I don't need to communicate with the spawned program. Is the fork() required?

Comment: Probably not, but I'm not certain (since I am spoiled with having access to NSTask and threads and all that).  Try just the execl and see how it goes.

Comment: Doesn't work for some reason. I've tried: execl("/Application/Myprog.app") and execl("Macintosh HD/Application/Myprog.app") Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `execl("/Applications/Myprog.app/Contents/MacOS/Myprog")` (replace "Myprog" with the name of the app, of course). In a standard MacOS application package, the true application binary lives within the .app... inside a MacOS and a Contents directory.

Comment: I had forgotten about that, but still no joy, but I can access it from Terminal, so the path is correct. The target is a 32-bit app. Are there any issues for a 64 to exec a 32?